# Sharp edges on blurred background

Tags: html, css, css-filters

For a site I am currently working on, I need a header that has a blurred background. I used the css `::before` to do this, but I need to retain the sharp edges.

**Here is what I currently get:**

(You might need to open it in full-screen to see the blurred edge.)

[image: My failed attempt at a blurred background]

The code of what I have right now is: ([View on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reNmoz?editors=1100))

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60%;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Header background */

.header::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  min-height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/1000/662/any) no-repeat fixed top;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px) contrast(125%) brightness(75%);
          filter: blur(5px) contrast(125%) brightness(75%);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor osit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</header>
```

**Whilst I want it to look like this:**

[image: What I'm trying to get]

I tried adding a container div, set to `overflow: hidden`, so that I could make the background slightly bigger, so it would be clipped and the burred edges would be hidden, but that didn't work. I'd also rather *not* have to have an unnecessary div, since that is the whole reason I used `::before` for the background image.

I can't think of any other solutions, and all the solutions that I can find for how to get a sharp edge on blur filters are for images, and do not work for background images, so how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Why not blur the image itself BTW?

Comment: @Aziz I'm going to later convert the whole site into a theme for a CMS, so the user will be able to choose what the background will be, and I want the blur to be consistent. I suppose I could use PHP to blur the image, but that didn't occur to me until now haha. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I see. Some users might complain "Why is my background blurred?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a correct way to solve this. The blur filter affects the entire element, including edges. You can *hide* the edges by making the element bigger than it's container, while the parent gets `overflow:hidden;` - See demo:

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body { height: 100%; }

.blurred {
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:3px solid #FFF;
  padding:1em;
  color:#FFF;
}

.blurred:before {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/1000/662/any) no-repeat fixed top;
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px) contrast(125%) brightness(75%);
  filter: blur(5px) contrast(125%) brightness(75%);
  content:"";
  height: 110%; width: 110%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0; left:0;
}

.blurred.scaled:before {transform:scale(1.1);}
```

```html
<div class="blurred scaled">
Scaled background
</div>

<div class="blurred">
Normal background
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/h8x9tpz6/1/)**

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks so much! (I did try something similar, but I guess I must have missed something xD)

Comment: I scaled the background using `transform:scale`. Make sure to add any vendor prefixes for browser-compatibility - [caniuse: CSS3 2D Transform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)